# Cannot download zip archive from AZURE via REST API

Tags: azure, api, zip, archive

I am trying to download a zip archive from Azure via REST API using this Request Url and the C# code below.  The response StatusCode is 200 so I assume it is working.  But the zip file does not get downloaded to my computer.  What am I doing wrong?

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&scopePath={scopePath}&recursionLevel={recursionLevel}&includeContentMetadata={includeContentMetadata}&latestProcessedChange={latestProcessedChange}&download={download}&$format={$format}&versionDescriptor.version={versionDescriptor.version}&versionDescriptor.versionOptions={versionDescriptor.versionOptions}&versionDescriptor.versionType={versionDescriptor.versionType}&includeContent={includeContent}&resolveLfs={resolveLfs}&sanitize={sanitize}&api-version=6.0


public static void DownloadTest()
{
    var repository = "myrepository";
    var branch = "main";
    var url = $"https://dev.azure.com/{Constants.ORGANIZATION}/{Constants.PROJECT}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/items?path=/&versionDescriptor[versionOptions]=0&versionDescriptor[versionType]=0&versionDescriptor[version]={branch}&resolveLfs=true&$format=zip&api-version=6.0&download=true";

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/zip"));

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", Constants.PAT))));

            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to take the `response.Content` and write it to disk if the response body contains a zip.

Comment: I was able save the zip with this code.  

                    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(outputPath))
                    using (Stream input = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url).Result)
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(output);
                    }